# Sounds stop on Windows 10 after a while

Tags: windows-10, drivers, system-sounds

When I play music on my Laptop, it keeps playing for about 20 seconds then the sounds stop completely. I've checked the sound drivers and updated them to the latest version but didn't change anything. I could only listen to music using headset. What's the problem?

I've already tried restarting Windows Audio Services, disabling and re-enabling the Audio Device and reinstalling the Audio Driver but they didn't work.

I'm 90% sure it's a software problem.

Comment: If you can hear music via headphones (Bluetooth, 3.5mm) you can focus on the laptop speaker. Probably it's already defective but I don't want to make early assumptions.

Comment: @CaldeiraG When I insert handsfree and eject it again while playing music, speakers start playing the music but again after a while they stop working.

Comment: Try in Device Management to delete the audio device and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc now I have no sound at all.

Comment: Install back the driver that worked. What is the device for audio and which driver version is that?

Comment: @harrymc High Definition Audio Device 10.0.18362.1

Comment: Microsoft driver version 10.0.18362.1 supports many devices, but which one is yours? (You may find it in Device Manager.) Please also give your computer model.

Comment: @harrymc
Realtek HD Audio 10.0.18362.1.
MSI CX640 Core-i7 2670QM.

Comment: Realtek has a driver from 2017 in [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software) which you might try. As long as you know how to reinstall your current driver you don't need to [backup it](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Comment: @harrymc I installed this version of Driver but it didn't work again.

Comment: Why are you sure it's a software problem? You have tried both Microsoft and Realtek software and nothing changed. I would say it's time to look at hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95415/discussion-between-alireza-a2f-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's not a software problem. I list:

- You have tried both Microsoft and Realtek hardware drivers and experienced
  the same problem with both. The generic driver installed by deleting the device
  in Windows and rebooting didn't work at all.
- This happens with all audio formats and with all programs.

You have done everything possible with software except one: Reinstalling Windows.
It's up to you to decide whether you wish to Refresh or Reset Windows.
But if you do, then first better
[backup all drivers](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Otherwise, perhaps you should suspect hardware. You could first examine all
the connectors relating to audio on the motherboard and try to better reseat them,
then perhaps try another audio device (if possible with your hardware).

If the computer is recent enough to still be under warranty,
the simplest solution would be to use the warranty
(after backing up all your personal data).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had found that disabling windows audio, then reenabling helped. To find that, you can click the start button and simply type services and hit enter and it should open. Then look for "Windows Audio" and restart it. If that fixes the issue then you need to do a windows repair, this should fix that service. At least it did in my situation.
Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I've tried such things many times but it didn't come to anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after some moments (about 20 seconds) audio was disconnected completely in Windows 10, independently of HW or whatever. I just stopped "Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service" and audio was back again ("someone" activated it but perhaps you just need to restart it).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).